# Copying a UTF-8 URL from browser's address bar, gives only the ugly encoded one

Tags: url, browser, copy-paste, url-encoding

When I copy a UTF-8 URL from the browser's address bar (almost any browser on any os), then try to paste it in another text field (to post it on facebook or twitter for example), it gives only the decoded URL, which makes it ugly. For example, in the address bar, the URL appears like this one:

> [https://www.chaino.com/وذكر](https://www.chaino.com/%D9%88%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1)

But when trying to copy and paste it in any other place, it gives the following ugly url:

> https://www.chaino.com/%D9%88%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1

& if I wanted to get the original URL to use it in any place, I used to decode it in this [Raw URL Decoder - Online Tool](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/rawurldecode)

**Question is:** is there a short direct way to copy these kind of URLs, and paste it without this hideous process? (may be using chrome extensions or something)

Comment: Another good solution see at http://superuser.com/questions/480692/copying-unicode-symbols-from-firefox-address-bar-as-is#answers.

Comment: @HansGinzel looks promising, the issue is that that question is Firefox related only, while some answers here are more generic, thanks

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using a web browser.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can add a 'space' at the end of the URL in the address bar, then you can select it all and copy it directly.

Comment: For some weird reason on Chrome 61 it works only on `https` websites, but not with `http`

Comment: In Chrome 66 they apparently changed it. It stopped working :(

Comment: Works for firefox 65.0.2.

Comment: Works on Firefox 82.0.2 64

Comment: Opera web browser has no such issue, although, it is based on Chromium

Comment: In Chrome 98 copying without the first letter does the trick

Comment: @samuelg0rd0n, Just add the `space` to the **start** of the URL, and then copy all **except the added `space`** (Works on Chrome v99)

Comment: Add a comma at the front of the URL, and delete the preceding comma when the URL is copied

Comment: Change the URL in any way that makes Chrome think it's a search string and not a URL, and it'll work. For example, add a letter or a symbol at the beginning, or don't copy some initial part.

Answer (score 64):

You can select URL without selecting scheme (e.g. `http://`), and copy it. This will give you what you expected.

P.S. The point is to select only part of the link. E.g. you can select whole URL without first character and than add it manually.

Comment: I didn't know it could work :) , just one problem with it, usually `http://` isn't visible so if the domain doesn't start with a subdomain (i.e `www.`) like the example in the question, then I won't be able to copy only part of it, is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Copy everything except first character and than add it manually.

Comment: The only working solution, nice trick, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In Firefox 53+ you can set `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy` [about:config option](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) to `true`.

Comment: Woow, Firefox can do that ! :) .. if it weren't a Firefox-only answer, I would have accepted it right now .. I know it might look risky sometimes, but the option itself looks awesome, thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not a full answer to the main question which is not only about Firefox. Also, Firefox on Android doesn't have this feature sadly, it's only about desktop: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224951/17612

Answer (score 7):

The URI you get by copying from the address bar is the only valid URI the browser can give you.

From the RFC 3986 (and other URL RFCs):

> A URI is a sequence of characters from a very limited set: the
>   letters of the basic Latin alphabet, digits, and a few special
>   characters.

So: `https://www.chaino.com/وذكر`
Is an invalid URI, yet a valid IRI (International Resource Identifier), that your browser will convert to a valid URI while requesting the server over HTTP (HTTP does not allow IRI, only URI).

TL;DR: Your browser is giving you what you expect: A valid URI that you can use everywhere, not an IRI only supported here and here.

PS If "facebook or twitter for example" are kind, they may display a readable form to their users, so don't worry about giving an encoded form.

Comment: you are talking mostly about the naming here, but I just wanted a readable form of the URL to be shared with others easily, & the chrome extension I used in my answer is doing exactly what I wanted

Comment: He is not talking about naming but about standards, which is a huge difference. Even if the answer does not solve the asker's problem, it still contains critical information and I am glad it's here. Still, most people use browsers to do work with links, and for most browsers IRI and URIs are functionally the same, I suppose.

Comment: There's a difference between machine-usable and human-readable strings: The URI is a machine-usable string but OP seems to me looking for a human-readable string. When storing or referencing URLs you normally want a human-readable form because %XX%XX%XX%XX%XX isn't useful to any human and can't be proofread. Chrome understands IRIs so if the intention is for a human to see the string or for the string to be fed back to Chrome by a human then the human-readable one is preferred. URIs are better suited for passing information between programs when a human is not involved.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Chrome Extensions like below:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-cyrilic-urls/alnknpnpinldhpkjkgobkalmoaeolhnf

Comment: 20 May 2020 - It works on latest chrome. Thanks Ilya

Comment: @ronnefeldt, could you, please, delete/hide/edit this answer since the link in it doesn't work any more and returns 404.

Comment: @ronnefeldt, could you, please, instead of using a direct link to "Copy Unicode URLs" changed it to a link to my answer below in this thread. I would be glad to have some upvotes for an extension which I created. It's not very important to me, I just like upvotes. Thank you.

Comment: neither work ...

Answer (score 7):

Create a bookmark with this url: `javascript:console.log(prompt('copy (Control+C) this link:', decodeURIComponent(window.location)))`.

Click this bookmark on that page.

Example page: [https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=中文](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87)

Answer (score 5):

The best answer I found tell now is using this Chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-cyrilic-urls/alnknpnpinldhpkjkgobkalmoaeolhnf?hl=en-US

which enables me to copy the url (in a decoded state) with only one click :)

Comment: "URL in a decoded state" does not exists, see my response. But you still may call them IRIs, not URLs.

Comment: Concerning naming, it doesn't matter much to me, I just want the URL in its readable form, & the Chrome extension here did it pretty well for me :)

Comment: If you don't want yet another extension, see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Chrome and FireFox extension called "Copy Unicode URLs"](https://github.com/ilyaigpetrov/copy-unicode-urls/), which I created.
It is:

1. Open source.
2. Gives you an option to leave URL terminators encoded so, e.g., links that end with a dot will have that dot encoded and email clients won't wrongly recognize this dot as a sentence/URL terminator.

If you love my work then, please, donate some sum [here](https://github.com/ilyaigpetrov/copy-unicode-urls/wiki/Donate).

Answer (score 3):

Copy addres without 'h' in  http...
And past addres without 'h' and  sum first addres with 'h'

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.