# xpage in Chrome mailto links shows @ as %40

Tags: google-chrome, xpages, mailto

I need to show email on xPage. I use Icon with "mailto:" link to save space. It works well as clicked - opens new Notes email with clicked address. However when it is copied with "Copy email address" it has %40 instead of @ and users are complaining about that...

Here is the relevant code:

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link2">
  <xp:this.value>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:"mailTo:"+pData.getEmail();}]]>
  </xp:this.value>
  <xp:image id="image3" url="/mail.png" alt="e-mail..."></xp:image>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: <xp:link escape="true" id="link2">
    <xp:this.value>
 <![CDATA[#{javascript:"mailTo:"+pData.getEmail();}]]>
    </xp:this.value>
    <xp:image id="image3" url="/mail.png" alt="e-mail...">
    </xp:image>
</xp:link>

Comment: Escape = false should do the trick

Comment: nope, that was first I though and tried. And I check that again and still not does.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176661/copying-a-utf-8-url-from-browsers-address-bar-gives-only-the-ugly-encoded-one

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the email address with URLEncoder.encode():

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link2">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:"mailto:" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(pData.getEmail(), "utf-8")}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:image id="image3" url="/mail.png" alt="e-mail..."> </xp:image>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: Not working as well...
If the same info is places into label it shows normally with @
`code`<xp:link escape="false" id="link2"
 text="#{javascript:pData.getEmail()}">
 <xp:this.value escape="true">
  <![CDATA[#{javascript:"mailTo:"+pData.getEmail();}]]>
 </xp:this.value>
        <xp:image id="image3"
  url="/mail.png" alt="e-mail...">
 </xp:image>
 <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:link>
`code`