# Why clipboard of url is encoded?

Tags: url, encoding, urlencode

As we know, URL is encoded before it is sent. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

However, why is it encoded when it's copied to the clipboard?
I've been Googling it, but it's all about how to convert it. There's no post on why.

- Example

```
https://velog.io/@njh7799/뷰-공부-링크들
```

if I copy this link(ctrl + C)
and paste it(ctrl + V) to the other page or note, it becomes

```
https://velog.io/@njh7799/%EB%B7%B0-%EA%B3%B5%EB%B6%80-%EB%A7%81%ED%81%AC%EB%93%A4
```

[image: dd]

+ I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176661/copying-a-utf-8-url-from-browsers-address-bar-gives-only-the-ugly-encoded-one). However answers of this post says how to bypass, not why this happens.

Comment: Copied how from where exactly…?!

Comment: @deceze Sorry for clarity. I've added a example

Comment: Still, copy *from where*? From your browser's address bar? Because the address bar is rendering *some* encoded characters as readable characters for usability, but the *actual* URL must be encoded. When you copy it, you get the actual, validly encoded URL.

Comment: Yes from the browser's address bar. The question is, why does it gives *actual URL* not the unencoded URL? As it shows readable characters on address bar for usability, it would be nice if it gives readable characters when copy it. 
Well, I have nothing to say if Chrome set it up like that, but why would them make it uncomfortable? I'm curious about that.

Comment: If you want to copy the URL, presumably you want a *valid* URL. An unencoded URL is not valid.

Comment: It's the character set for the application that you are pasting it into that is the limiting factor

Comment: @Glenn It's not.